# Как поставить символ в значении столбца на нулевую позицию значения при выполнении определенного условия?

Tags: python, pandas, re

У меня есть DataFrame

```
d = {"city":['Лондон', 'Краков', 'Дамаск'], "year": ['50 н. е.','990', '2500 год до н. э.']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[1, 2, 3])
```

|  | city | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Лондон | 50 н. е. |
| 2 | Краков | 990 |
| 3 | Дамаск | 2500 год до н. э |

Нужно заменить '*до н. э*' на '-' и поставить его на нулевую позицию значения, а все остальные не числовые символы удалить.

То есть ожидаю получить:

|  | city | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Лондон | 50 |
| 2 | Краков | 990 |
| 3 | Дамаск | -2500 |

Знаю как удалить ненужные символы, но как поставить символ в начало, не понимаю.

```
re_express = re.compile('до н. э.')
df['year'] = df['year'].replace(re_express, '-')
re_express = re.compile('[а-яА-ЯёЁA-Za-z.]|\s')
df['year'] = df['year'].replace(re_express, '')
```

|  | city | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Лондон | 50 |
| 2 | Краков | 990 |
| 3 | Дамаск | 2500- |

Comment: `replace('(^.*) год до н. э.', r'-\1')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = (pd.to_numeric(df["year"].str.extract(r".*?(\d+).*")[0], errors="coerce")
       * np.where(df["year"].str.contains(r"до н. э."), -1, 1))
```

результат

```
In [49]: res
Out[49]:
1      50
2     990
3   -2500
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```